# Copying D3D11 subresource data

Tags: c++, hook, direct3d11

I have a quick question about Direct3D 11. I have implemented D3D DrawIndexed hook that copies current vertex buffer from GPU to CPU, modifies some data and copies it back to GPU.

Maybe I forgot about something, but even if I don't modify any data and just copy the data to CPU and back, the result is totally corrupted rendering.

The code snippet is:

```
m_pDeviceContext->IAGetIndexBuffer(&indexBuffer, &format, &offset);

// copy current region of the index buffer from GPU to CPU
D3D11_BOX box;
box.left = offset + StartIndexLocation * sizeof(unsigned __int16);
box.right = offset + (StartIndexLocation + IndexCount) * sizeof(unsigned __int16);
box.top = box.front = 0;
box.bottom = box.back = 1;
m_pDeviceContext->CopySubresourceRegion(cpuBuffer, 0, 0, 0, 0, indexBuffer, 0, &box);

D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource = { 0 };
hRes = m_pDeviceContext->Map(cpuBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedResource);
if (hRes == S_OK) {
    // now read all indexes and find the min and max index
    std::vector<unsigned __int16> indexes((unsigned __int16*)mappedResource.pData, (unsigned __int16*)mappedResource.pData + IndexCount);
    auto minmax = std::minmax_element(indexes.begin(), indexes.end());
    m_pDeviceContext->Unmap(cpuBuffer, 0);

    // get the vertex buffer
    UINT stride, offset;
    CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> vertexBuffer;
    m_pDeviceContext->IAGetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // copy the region where the min index and max index points to
    box.left = BaseVertexLocation + *minmax.first * stride;
    box.right = BaseVertexLocation + *minmax.second * stride + stride;
    m_pDeviceContext->CopySubresourceRegion(cpuBuffer, 0, 0, 0, 0, vertexBuffer, 0, &box);

    // now I am able to Map/Unmap cpuBuffer and access the data in memory - the data are correct
    // ...

    // copy data back to GPU vertex buffer
    // it results in corrupted rendering - it seems that data are copied to wrong location
    box.right = box.right - box.left;
    box.left = 0;
    m_pDeviceContext->CopySubresourceRegion(vertexBuffer, 0, BaseVertexLocation + *minmax.first * stride, 0, 0, cpuBuffer, 0, &box);
```

Is there any reason why the last CopySubResourceRegion would copy to the wrong location and thus corrupt the original vertex buffer?

I assume that the vertices are sorted by their index, that's why I copy region between min and max.

EDIT: I tested the following simple code snippet and even just copying from GPU to CPU and back to GPU results in rendering corruption, although the vertex buffer is unmodified. I enabled D3D Debug Layer and no error is logged during the operation.

```
box.left = 0;
box.right = desc.ByteWidth;
m_pDeviceContext->CopySubresourceRegion(cpuBuffer, 0, 0, 0, 0, vertexBuffer, 0, &box);
m_pDeviceContext->CopySubresourceRegion(vertexBuffer, 0, 0, 0, 0, cpuBuffer, 0, &box);
```

Comment: Maybe you are hitting the known issue on Feature Level 9.x hardware mentioned in the Remarks section of the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11devicecontext-copysubresourceregion)?

Comment: The note seems to be interesting, but I don't pass NULL source box and I even verified that source and destionation resources are the same size. I tried even to pass source box that is the full size and nothing changed.

Comment: And one more interesting thing to mention - after copying the data from CPU to GPU, I tried copying them back to CPU and read them (Map/Unmap) again. But the data are not modified at all, they still contain original data. So it means that CopySubresourceRegion from CPU to GPU copies to some absolutely wrong location.